# Booting Into a TTY with No Graphics?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, console, init

I'm a little new to this so I apologize if my question is hard to follow.

I'm running Arch Linux, systemd as the init system, and I would like to boot into a plain TTY with no graphics. I've tried to disable the display manager I am currently using, as well as set the default target to multi-user, but I'm greeted with a blank screen whenever I boot up. I have to pull out the installation CD and chroot in every time this happens, as the typical keyboard shortcut to switch to a TTY does not work. How would I go about setting it up to boot into a plain TTY? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read through this helpful page of the Arch Wiki: [Systemd Targets](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Targets). Systemd targets are roughly equivalent to the old runlevels when everything used the init system. Change your target from 5(multi-user graphical) to 3(multi-user no graphics). This should drop you into a terminal login screen upon boot. If you want to go graphical just type "startx."

Comment: You should note the command at least. `systemctl set-default multi-user.target`